# Slice and concatenate columns without using numpy.r_

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, iteration

I want to iterate my function for each item in multiple columns, within which there are 2 columns that I don't want to select, i.e. `df.iloc[:,58:72]` and `df.iloc[:,74:92]`. I know `numpy.r_` works, but is there any other way to get the same outcome?

My code:

```
char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\\"
def remove_char(x):
    try:
        return float(x.strip(char))
    except:
        return None
for columnName in df.iloc[:,np.r_[58:72,74:92]]:
    df[columnName] = list(map(remove_char, df[columnName]))
```

Comment: Use pd.concat, `pd.concat([df.iloc[:, 58:72 ], df.iloc[:, 74:92]], axis=1)`

Comment: `df.iloc[:,np.r_[58:72,74:92]] = df.iloc[:,np.r_[58:72,74:92]].applymap(remove_char)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat` instead:

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, 58:72 ], df.iloc[:, 74:92]], axis=1)
```